# How to plot a Gamma distribution in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, gamma-distribution

I have a plot in R that I am trying to replicate in ggplot2. I have the following code:

```
theta = seq(0,1,length=500)
post <- dgamma(theta,0.5, 1)
plot(theta, post, type = "l", xlab = expression(theta), ylab="density", lty=1, lwd=3)
```

[image]

I have tried to replicate this plot in ggplot2 and this is the closest I was able to get.

```
df=data_frame(post,theta)
ggplot(data=df,aes(x=theta))+
  stat_function(fun=dgamma, args=list(shape=1, scale=.5))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't match up your parameters correctly. The signature of `dgamma` is

```
dgamma(x, shape, rate = 1, scale = 1/rate, log = FALSE)
```

so when you call

```
dgamma(theta, 0.5, 1)
```

that's

```
dgamma(theta, shape=0.5, rate=1)
```

which means you would translate the `ggplot` as

```
ggplot(data=df,aes(x=theta))+
  stat_function(fun=dgamma, args=list(shape=0.5, rate=1))
```

you could also adjust the y-limits if you like with `scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,12))` or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for the help!